# Как выбрать год из промежутка

Tags: sql, postgresql

подскажите пожалуйста как выбрать год из промежутка. Например с 2012 и по сегодняшний день
Последняя попытка была такая
`WHERE year = ((extract(YEAR FROM (now()::timestamp))-2012 * random() + 2012))::int`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ((extract(YEAR FROM (now()::timestamp))-2012) * random() + 2012)::int
```

Comment: Я был близок к решению)  Спасибо